# Import @types from private scoped npm

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, typescript-typings

I have a private, scoped npm package, the package.json of which looks like this:

```
    {
      "name": "@co/schema",
      "version": "0.20.0",
      "author": "jsmith",
      "contributors": [],
      "main": "lib/index.js",
      "files": [
        "lib"
      ],
      "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "12.7.4",
        "graphql": "14.5.6",
        "typescript": "3.6.2"
      }
    }
```

I have installed this package in another project.  Problem is:  when trying to import a specific type from it:

```
import { Derp } from '@co/schema';
```

The import itself shows no error, but when I try to use the type:

```
myDerp: Derp = {};
```

I get this error:  `cannot use namespace Derp as a type`.

So, Derp is definitely NOT a namespace.  It's an interface:

```
export interface Derp {
  herp: string,
  nerp: number,
  flerp: string
}
```

A suggested fix I saw was: `npm i @types/@co/schema -D` but when I try to do that, I get:

```
code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
Invalid package name "@types/": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

Can't tell if that's balking at the @ in my scope name or what.

So yes - how do I correctly import (or export from my private module) these types?

I have removed all **default** exports, since I saw that recommended somewhere.  So every type/interface/whatever is being exported individually instead of via default.  But I'm kinda stumped now and don't know what else to try.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, I have defined typings in the package.json, but unable to consume it.